Can I run the Pthreads library directly on a virtual machine
So, I have installed a virtual machine (kali linux), I would like to know if I can complete my assignment, which requires multiple processes to be created and managed using Pthreads library in C. She has suggested us to dual boot, but unfortunately, my laptop does not have too much space left (approximately 40GB). Therefore, I would like to know, if i can use the Pthreads and its functionality to the fullest extent or go for the dual boot option.
I have installed the VirtualBox and kali machine on it, but I don't know how to run this pthreads in C programs

but I don't know how to run this pthreads in C programs... Ok, but that's a different problem.

You don't run a library, you make a program that uses the library and run that. And you can do that in Kali running on Virtualbox, sure. If you want true concurrency, assign more than one CPU to the VM.

Using WSL is also an option, simpler than a full VM, either way is simpler than dual booting, which is an inflexible and somewhat heavyweight solution. Does anybody do that these days?  Yes it will work.


So, I have installed a virtual machine (kali linux), I would like to
know if I can complete my assignment, which requires multiple
processes to be created and managed using Pthreads library in C.

There is no particular reason why you should not be able to build and run pthreads-using programs in your Kali VM.  You will of course have only the (virtual) resources provided by that VM, but there is no inherent problem with that.

She
has suggested us to dual boot, but unfortunately, my laptop does not
have too much space left (approximately 40GB).

40 GB would probably be more than enough for a Linux installation that does not include any GUI components, but making the machine dual boot is very invasive.  I'm surprised that your instructor did not suggest Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), which would probably be the easiest option.

Therefore, I would like
to know, if i can use the Pthreads and its functionality to the
fullest extent or go for the dual boot option.

It depends on what you mean by "to the fullest extent".  You can use pthreads even with only one core, and you can use multiple cores in your VM if it in fact is configured to provide them.

I have installed the VirtualBox and kali machine on it, but I don't
know how to run this pthreads in C programs

If you mean that you don't know how to use the pthreads API, then your course materials and instructor should be your first recourse.  Without considerable refinement, that's far too broad for this venue.
If you mean you don't know how to use the system's tools to build pthreads programs from source then you should again look first to your course for support, but we can answer specific questions about problems you run into in that area.
If you literally mean that you don't know how to run pthreads programs once they are built, then nothing special is required.  You run such programs just like you would any other.

You can use pthreads even with only one core, and you can use multiple cores in your VM if it in fact is configured to provide them. Just to mention, to configure the VM to use multiple cores, this is done from VirtualBox config/console from Windows [e.g. If the physical laptop has 8 cores, allow the VM to use all of them]. Then, launch the kali VM. After that, you're in "real" linux environment. You use bash, xterm, vim, gcc and any other linux tools you need. When I've used VirtualBox before, once so configured, I've done all work under linux (for days/weeks at a time).

Thank you for the clarification, I will learn more about this library and I will try to complete the assignment on a VM. I will get back to you if it works out.
